# how to make User instance

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-urls

i have two applications in my django project accounts and bp
in account application i have a custom user model

accounts/models.py:

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser):
     email = models.EmailField(unique=True, max_length=255)
     is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
     #other fields
```

accounts/views.py:

```
def signup(request):
    form = RegistrationForm()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        registration_form = RegistrationForm(request.POST)
        if registration_form.is_valid():
            user = registration_form.save(commit=False)
            user.is_active = True
            user.save()
            user_id=user.id
            return redirect(reverse('bp:profile',kwargs={'user_id':user_id}))
    
        return render(request,'signup.html',{'form':form})
```

bp/models.py:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    #other fields
```

bp/views.py

```
def profile(request,user_id):

    if request.method =='POST':
    
        form = NewProfileForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            profile=form.save(commit=False)
            profile.user=User.objects.get(id=user_id)
            profile.save()
    else:
        form=NewProfileForm()
    return render(request,'profile.html',{'form':form})
```

bp/urls.py :

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('profile/<int:user_id>/',views.profile, name='profile'),
]
```

after creating the user it redirect me to profile html after writing the data when i submit it show me this error[image]

can you help me please